# What is the dialog box called after clicking <input type='file' /> on iOS Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari

I'm trying to figure out how to determin

1. the `onClose` of this dialog.
2. the `onOpen` of `Photo Library` or `Take Photo or Video` or `Browse` (which I think can just be solved by having a visibility listener on the document.

[image]

Comment: I seriously doubt you're going to be able to do that. The file chooser dialog on all browsers is firewalled from the code on the page; it's a browser facility (like the "Print" dialog).

Comment: I mostly figured it out. https://gist.github.com/alex-cory/0b0b59cef8cd402b751e6e33bef12238